# How can I persist the chain state of Truffle develop?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Is it possible to persist the chain state of Truffle develop? 
If my truffle console crash, can I restore the chain state?

Answer (score 0):

You can create fixtures - i.e. put your dataset in the form of a JS script, similar to truffle based tests, and run it when you start working with your dev environment. This way you'll have something in your blockchain to work with, and won't have to add it manually every time.